# INSERT INTO MySQLi statement not working after first time

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli, sql-insert

I have a pretty standard MySQL insert into statement that doesn't seem to be working. I'm posting an HTML form to this page and it's translating the information and inserting into the table (pending_jobs). It worked the first time and hasn't worked since. I'm not looking to UPDATE the row but add a brand new one every time this code is submitted so I figured this would be pretty simple. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
$id=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$company_name = $row['company_name'];
$date_registered = $row['date_registered'];
$job_title=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['jobtitle']);
$job_description=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['jobdescription']);
$salary=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['salary']);
$industry_sector=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['industry']);
$number_people=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['num_people']);

if(isset($_POST['payment']) && $_POST['payment']=='yes'){
$payment_received = 'Yes';
}
else{
$payment_received = 'No';
}

$sql_add = "INSERT INTO pending_jobs (company_name, job_title) VALUES ('$company_name', '$job_title')";
$result_add = $mysqli->query($sql_add);

if(isset($result_add)){
  session_start();
  $id = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  header('location:profile.php?id='.$id);
} else {
echo "<script>alert('".$job_title."');</script>";
}
?>
```

It is redirecting to the profile.php page so I know that $result_add is actually going through but when I check the table in the database there is no new row. Any ideas on why it wouldn't be creating a new row?

Comment: Interesting case... Have you set any of the fields to `UNIQUE`? That would explain the silent failing. You could try to fetch errors: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `query` to

```
$result_add = $mysqli->query($sql_add) or die($mysqli->error);
```

and you will see the problem at once.
Also

```
 if (isset($result_add)) {
```

will always be true, because `$result_add` will be either `true` or `false` for your insert.

Comment: That's great! It was a mistake on made on the structure of the table. The company_name variable was accidentally set as the primary index so it wouldn't let me do two of the same row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unique columns or indexes could prevent this insert statement. Simply test the same insert in phpmyadmin, or the mysql console. Also, isset() will be true even if $result_add is false :)

Answer (score 0):

try to return the error in case the statement fails, so you know what's wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die("cannot select from users");

$result_add = $mysqli->query($sql_add) or die("cannot insert");
```

( some propose `or trigger_error(mysqli->error.$result_add);` but I haven't tested this).

```
replace `if(isset($result_add)){` with `if($result_add){
```

The suggestion to look at the table is also a nice one.